# How to predict random and fixed effect models?

Tags: r, glm, predict, generic-function

I just recently made a change from STATA to R and have some troubles implementing the R equivalent of the STATA commands `xtlogit,fe or re`and `predict`. May I ask for some assistance to adjust the following scenario:

```
  data <- read.table("http://people.stern.nyu.edu/wgreene/Econometrics/healthcare.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

   require(caret) # for confusionMatrix

   #### subset into test & train according to the panel nature (split  individuals rather then observations)
   nID <- length(unique(data$id))
   p = 0.50# partition

   inTrain <- sample(unique(data$id), round(nID * p), replace=FALSE)

   training <- data[data$id %in% inTrain, ] 

   testing <- data[!data$id %in% inTrain, ] 


   pooled <- glm(WORKING~WHITEC+FEMALE+BLUEC+HHNINC+AGE+AGESQ+EDUC+DOCVIS,data=training, family=binomial(link="logit"))

   prediction.working= round(predict(pooled,newdata=testing,type="response"))

   confusionMatrix(prediction.working,testing$WORKING) # Accuracy between both
```

Additionally, I would like to do these procedure for random effects and fixed effects. So I tried random effects first unsuccessfully:

```
   library(glmmML)
   RE <- glmmML(WORKING~WHITEC+FEMALE+BLUEC+HHNINC+AGE+AGESQ+EDUC+DOCVIS, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=training, cluster=id, method="ghq", n.points=12)



    prediction.working= round(predict(RE,newdata=testing,type="response"))
```

But that doesnt seem to work. May I ask for how to adjust the `glm`model regarding random effects and fixed effects in order to use the `predict`function.

Comment: I think you are looking for conditional logit model. Try http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclogit/mclogit.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to R.  I am also a STATA convert.

This is a tricky problem, but its answer is essential to understand.  To understand why the `predict` function does not work for glmmML you need to understand S3 methods (see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html).

Let me explain a bit.  R is an object oriented language.  This means that everything in R is an object (i.e. vector, function, data.frame).  Each object contain attributes.  An attribute is essentially meta-data about the object itself.  For example the names of variables in a data.frame are attributes.   One attribute all objects have is a class.  To see the class of any object just call the `class()` function.

A lot, but not all, functions use S3 methods.  The `predict` function is one of these function.  This means when you call `predict`, the `predict` function looks at the class of the object.  Then depending on the class picks which other predict function should be used.  For example, if your object is class `lm`, the predict function will call the `predict.lm` function.  Other `predict` functions include: `predict.glm` for objects of `glm` class, `predict.loess` for objects of `loess` class, `predict.nls` for objects of `nls` class, etc. (to see the full list read the `predict` help).  Unfortunately, no `predict.glmmML` function exists.  Consequently, when you call the `predict` function on a object of class `glmmML` you get an error.

```
id <- factor(rep(1:20, rep(5, 20)))
y <- rbinom(100, prob = rep(runif(20), rep(5, 20)), size = 1)
x <- rnorm(100)
dat <- data.frame(y = y, x = x, id = id)
fit.2 <- glmmML(y ~ x, data = dat, cluster = id)
predict(fit.2)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "glmmML"
class(fit.2)
 [1] "glmmML"
```

The error is very informative.  It basically says that R tried to use S3 methods, however, there was no 'predict.glmmML'

What about the `mclogit` function which user227710 suggests. Let's see

```
data(Transport)

fit <- mclogit(
  cbind(resp,suburb)~distance+cost,
  data=Transport
)

class(fit)
[1] "mclogit" "lm"
```

The class of `fit` is `mclogit` and `lm`.  Will `predict` work?  Yes!  When you call `predict(fit)` the `predict` function will first look for a `predict.mclogit`, which does not exist.  It will next look for `predict.lm`.  Which does exist.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Accordind to the manuel of mclogit one can just specify random effects. May I ask you how to determine the prediction for fixed effects with that library? THX

Comment: Additionally one has to create response counts as suggested in your exampple with  `cbind(resp,suburb)`